# Can you solve this fuel consumption equation?

Tags: pilot-technique

> Nasair 300, radar contact at 2205z, maintain flight level 300 report
>   36 nm from present position.

If the ground speed is 360 knots, and fuel flow is 2400 kg/hr; what approximate time will Nasair 300 flight report 36 nm and how much approximate fuel will it burn from its present position to 36 nm, respectively?

Comment: This is arithmetic. Is this your homework?

Comment: Nope, it's a prep question for a test I'm about to take that I couldn't figure out.

Comment: homework or prep question does not make a big of a difference for us, we still prefer to know why you could not answer that question by yourself, so to give an answer that will help you understand better, instead of an answer that says "it's like this"

Comment: I have the answer in hand before posting the question I wanted to know how it came out to 240 kg and 6 min. I don't see why you making a big deal about it, this is what the website for sharing knowledge and helping each other.

Comment: Because that's the way this website works, we do not like questions that ask "please solve this equation" without explaining *why* you're not able to solve it yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is just asking for someone to do his study homework.

Comment: Hello Abdull. The issue that people seem to have is not so much about the question itself, but the way it is asked. If you would rephase the question in such a way that a) you explain the context (i.e. you are studying and you came accross this question), b) you explain what you have tried to solve it. c) you ask what the appropriate way is to calculate the answer to such a question, then I don't think anybody would object. The way people interpret your question now is: "here is my exam question, please give me the number so I can answer and pass my exam without understanding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $ v = 360 $ knots ground speed it will take one tenth of an hour to travel $ d = 36 $ NM:

$$ t = \frac{d}{v} = \frac{36 \, \mathrm{NM}}{360 \, \mathrm{NM} / \mathrm{h}} = 6 \, \mathrm{min}, $$

which means at 22:11Z. At a fuel flow of $ \dot{m} = 2400 $ kg/h, the plane will then burn 240 kg of fuel:

$$ m_\mathrm{Fuel} = t \times \dot{m} = \frac{1 \mathrm{h}}{10} \times 2400 \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{h}} = 240 \, \mathrm{kg} $$

Comment: next time, please avoid giving the solution before it is clear what the OP needs help with. these answers hold little to no value to future users, and we're not here to do the homework of others.

Comment: @Federico OK, will do next time! I thought it might be helpful to see how to compute fuel based on distance, ground speed and fuel flow in general...

Comment: In other words, your homework...

Comment: @Abdull, Federico was in no way attacking anybody. The community on this website tries to focus on explaining how to solve this kind of problems, rather than just providing the answer.

Comment: Sure, it can be helpful, but addressing specific things/doubts/questions can be more helpful.

Comment: @JuanJimenez if you say so...

Comment: Yes, @Abdull, both I and Federico say so, and I vote to delete this question.